# Polymer and bootstrap issue with chrome

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, google-chrome, import, polymer

I've got a strange issue with Bootstrap and Polymer.

I built my whole website using polymer and his power, but when I just want to use column bootstrap layout on my website, it's not working with Chrome. But it's not a problem with Safari or Firefox.

I've tried to import CSS into main.css with an @import, I've imported the CSS into my template, into the head, at the end, but it's still the same issue: Chrome don't want to read Bootstrap's CSS file.

Have I missed something?

Comment: Is it giving a 404 error when it @imports the css? Check the console for errors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Polymer elements have a shadow DOM, that isolate them from external styles
If you put a css file in the body, it will be ignored by the polymer elements (except the html /deep/ styles, but bootstrap css does not have these styles)

Comment: If I'm understanding, you mean that css into my index file cannot go deep throw shadow dom and give classes to my elements ? But i've tried to import this CSS inside my custom element and the issue is still the same : works on Safari and FF but not chrome...

Comment: As you can see in the polymer styling documentation : "Because polyfilling the styling behaviors of Shadow DOM is difficult, Polymer has opted to favor practicality and performance over correctness. For example, the polyfill’s do not protect Shadow DOM elements against document level CSS"
Firefox and safari don't implement WebComponent natively yet. This is not a Chrome bug, this is the expected behaviour. (you should have the same behaviour in FF in the next releases, or if you enable the webcomponents). Importing the css in each component may work depending on how the css is written...